# How to detect whether any form elements have been filled in via autofill?

Tags: javascript, forms, dom-events, autofill

I have a login form where I need to do the following:

- allow autofill so users who want to login without typing can continue to do so
- detect whether autofill was used on the form so when user later tries to access parts of the site which require login without autofill, I only prompt the user to login again (with a different version of the login form that instead does NOT allow autofill) if they used autofill on the first form

At present I haven't found a way to reliably detect whether autofill was used (IE, Firefox, Chrome, Google Toolbar, etc. --> any mechanism by which the form fields get filled out without the user typing would count here as "autofill"). So for now I'm simply letting users login the first time without autofill (since that's an important business requirement) and then prompting them to login from the autofill-disabled form when they get to a sensitive part of the site, even if they had as a matter of fact typed their username and password on the first form.

If anyone's found a reliable way to **detect** (not block) all forms of autofill, I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: p.s. a rough idea of one approach would be to use javascript to log each time a keystroke occurs in any of the input fields (measure how much information was entered manually, making sure to handle the special case of when user clicks delete or backspace) and then check that against how many characters are present in the input fields on submit. If the number is different, that would seem to indicate autofill had been used. But this is just an untested idea, would remain to be seen whether this would work on, say IE6+, FF3+, Chrome, Safari. Assumes all inputs have empty defaults.

Comment: Timing the keystrokes + checking input length versus number of keystrokes (after considering backspace, delete etc..) would be an imperfect way to go about it. But it still wouldn't be fool proof or perfect. We wont be able to differentiate between auto-filled data and pasted data (from clipboard).

Answer (score 0):

I hate say it but, you can't and more importantly you(the developer) are not expected to be able too.

You have to imagine the auto-fill built into browsers today is the old auto-fill applications  of yesteryear. They sat outside the browser DOM influence and literally polled known windows for known properties i.e. forms and sent key strokes directly as if the user had typed them.

The current browsers have auto-fill options built in but, they are still as non-standard as the old applications and as such not (reliably) detectable.

Either ignore them or always blank input fields via JavaScript.